Ansible playbook: how to use OAuth from credentials in Tower?
I am having trouble passing the OAuth token from a credential in Ansible Tower.
I have a credential setup in Tower with these settings:

Name: cred_tower_oauth
Credential Type: Red Hat Ansible Automation Platform
Type Details:
Red Hat Ansible Automation Platform: ***********
Username: ******
Password: 
OAuth Token: ***********

My playbook is like this:
- name: Access API with OAuth Token from Ansible Tower Credential
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Access API with OAuth Token
      uri:
        url: "https://api.example.com/data"
        method: GET
        headers:
          Authorization: "Bearer {{ oauth_token }}"
        return_content: yes
      register: api_response

    - name: Display token
      debug:
        msg: "token: {{oauth_token}}"

How do I get the OAuth token in my credential in Ansible Tower and insert it in my var oauth_token?

I found it:
lookup('env','TOWER_OAUTH_TOKEN')

